# Unison: always use 'copyprog' for updates

Tags: filesystems, rsync, unison, ownership

I am using Unison to synchronize files between several clients. Each client is identical, meaning that whenever one client updates a certain file, all other clients must be updated consequently.

The files are stored in a centralized cloud server. Each client has non-root SSH access to the centralized cloud server. There is no link between the clients.

It's important that ownership of the files is preserved. For this reason, I am using `--rsync-path="rsync --fake-super"` below. This stores the owner/group in the extended file attributes, so ownership on the client can be restored during synchronization afterwards. That said, if there is a better method to preserve ownership, feel free to let me know, as this might also eliminate the problem below.

A relevant snippet from the configuration is as following:

```
copythreshold = 0
copyprog      = /usr/bin/rsync -avzX --rsync-path="rsync --fake-super" --inplace -e ssh
copyprogrest  = /usr/bin/rsync -avzX --rsync-path="rsync --fake-super" --inplace --partial -e ssh
```

I observe the following behavior:

1. When a file is **created**, rsync as configured in `copyprog` is used to transfer the files.

   This is great, because now the newly created file has the `user.rsync.%stat` attribute set (which holds the owner/group) on the cloud server. A consecutive synchronization on the other clients will indeed preserve the ownership.
2. However, when the file is **updated**, rsync as configured in `copyprog` is not used. I believe Unison does some custom built-in transfer logic instead.

   This is not so great, because now the `user.rsync.%stat` attribute is lost on the cloud server. A consecutive synchronization on the other clients will now loose the owernship.

Is it possible to configure Unison such that `copyprog` is also always used for updates? The documentation mentions:

> If you set copythreshold to 0, Unison will use the external copy utility for all **whole-file** transfers.

Unfortunately, nothing is mentioned about updates.

Comment: Did you try using `unison -debug all` to get more information on what is being done?

Comment: @meuh Yes, that's how I debugged the behavior as described in the question. For a new file, I noticed that rsync was used, while for an updated file, rsync was not used. Should I add that debug output to the question?

Comment: If you can reduce the output to just a few relevant lines, please add it. I see `unison` is written in the OCaml language, so it might be difficult to understand what it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced the problem you see, and looked through the very verbose debug output, and the OCaml [copy.ml](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/blob/master/src/copy.ml) code (I am not familiar with this language) but did not see any obvious reason for why it could not use the `copyprog` setting.

However, [this](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/issues/65) issue from February 2017 says that  *copyprog only works for new files* (`copyprogrest` is for continuing an interrupted `copyprog`). A fix for that would probably also solve your problem. It is now marked as an enhancement.  You might like to post a new issue there giving your use case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking your time to reproduce this. I was looking to that same code, but am having troubles understanding OCaml as well. I'll create a post on the github repo and refer to this question. Thanks!

Comment: It can be found here: https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/issues/219